# What does "type Task x a = Task" mean in the Elm implementation of Task?

Tags: elm

In this [Github example](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/2.1.0/src/Task.elm), Task type is defined as follow:

`type Task x a = Task`

And then follow several functions that make use of this type.

How the Task type is supposed to be understood?

What does it mean when we define a type as:

`type Foo a b = Foo`

Is Task a specific case where we rely on the native javascript implementation of Task?

Answer (score 6):

> Is Task a specific case where we rely on the native javascript implementation of Task?

Exactly. You'll notice that `Task` the type but not `Task` the tag (thing on the right) are exported from the module, so you can't actually access the latter. It's a placeholder to make the type system happy.

Instead, the Native JavaScript implementation knows what tasks *really* are, which is [a JS object](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/2.1.0/src/Native/Task.js#L18-L58). Any native module dealing with Tasks (either the `Task` module or any third-party library like `elm-http`) is in on the secret. However, the `Task` module exports a good number of helper functions that you can have a lot of control over tasks using only the already published libraries.

Clarification Edit: Yes, you need to use a third-party library to get a task that actually does some effect in the outside world. To actually run that task, you need to send it out a port; until you do that a Task is just a *description* of the work to do.

Comment: If I understand, async tasks can only be created from the JS side. Am I right?

Comment: Also feels like a tasks means many things: a result of a task and the task itself (async process).  I have a hard time to get around the task concept.

Comment: @Martinos: From the perspective of an Elm user, a task is just data. It's a value that describes an async process, and once it's handed off to a port in the right way, the runtime will interpret the task to actually run it.

Comment: I think I will need to meditate on that a bit. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it's creating a kind of wild card.

In the following code:

```
import  Html exposing (..)

type Dog a = Fido

myFunc: Dog Int -> String
myFunc myDog =
  "Wouf Wouf" 

main = text (myFunc Fido)
```

`myFunc` expects a `Dog Int`. You can then send `Fido` to the method.